# How to make a loop run up to when it stops making sense?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, while-loop

I have a loop inside a program which should be

```
while number >= lst[count]:
    rank -= 1
    count += 1
```

where I would like the while to run until it stops making sense. I've attempted somethings which have not worked (see the end of the post), but the following has worked:

```
lst = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
number = int(input())
count = 0
rank = 0

def attempt(lst, a):
    try:
        result = lst[a]
    except:
        result = float('inf')
    return result


while number >= attempt(lst, count):
    rank -= 1
    count += 1
print(rank)
```

However, I don't think this is very elegant and seems contrived. Is there a more elegant solution (for this case, and also in general for a given condition)?

---

Other attempts (which were unsuccessful):

```
while aliceScores[i] >= lst[count] and count < len(lst):
    rank -= 1
    count += 1
```

The above fails because the while tries to run for count = len(lst) and runs an error, since lst[len(lst)] does not exist.

```
while aliceScores[i] >= lst[count] and count < len(lst)-1:
    rank -= 1
    count += 1
```

The above fails because I want to modify the rank if the condition happens also in the case lst[len(lst) - 1], which would not be seem in the above code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only reason why

```
while aliceScores[i] >= lst[count] and count < len(lst):
    rank -= 1
    count += 1
```

does not work is that you cannot evaluate lst[count] when count is too big, however you can exploit the fact python [short-circuits and/or operators](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not)

```
while count < len(lst) and aliceScores[i] >= lst[count]:
    rank -= 1
    count += 1
```

This way the loop will stop properly either if count is too big, or if the second condition becomes False.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. It is a little strange that "and" is not effectively commutative.

Comment: It's a nearly universal convention for the boolean operators to short-circuit, which is far more useful than commutativity would be.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a `for` to iterate the list, and an `enumerate` to count the number of tries.
It would be more pythonic than a `while` imho.

```
def get_rank(...):
   for index, lst_number in enumerate(lst):
       if number < lst_attempt:
           return -index
   return -len(lst)
```